# How to access the index of an item in knockout.js template

Tags: knockout.js

Within my template in tbody below, how can I access the index of the item being rendered?

```
<table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:contacts">
            <tr class="contactRow" valign="top">
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: function(){viewModel.removeContact($data)}">Delete</td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: FirstName" name="Contacts[].FirstName"/></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: LastName" name= "Contacts[].LastName"  /></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: Username"  name="Contacts[].Username"/></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: Email"   name="Contacts[].Email"/></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Controls</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update: `$index` is now available in KO 2.1.

Currently, there is not a way to directly access the index in a `foreach`.  There is a pull request that looks at adding a `$index` variable here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/182

An option that I have used in the past is to use a manual subscription against an observableArray that keeps an index observable in sync.

It works like:

```
//attach index to items whenever array changes
viewModel.tasks.subscribe(function() {
    var tasks = this.tasks();
    for (var i = 0, j = tasks.length; i < j; i++) {
       var task = tasks[i];
        if (!task.index) {
           task.index = ko.observable(i);  
        } else {
           task.index(i);   
        }
    }
}, viewModel);
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/CXBFN/

Comment: +1. This is exactly what I was looking for to workaround lack of the nth-child(even) in IE7/8

Answer (score 6):

I'm doing this and it's working pretty well.  Not the best looking, but keeps everything in order:

Use the attr: binding to set the name attribute of your field and then use `$parent.CallForwards.indexOf($data)`
to get your index.

```
data-bind="value: Name, attr: {name: 'CallForwards[' + $parent.CallForwards.indexOf($data) + '].Name'}"
```

Comment: I think this is clean and nice!

Comment: Not only this is clean and nice it also allow us to access index in the deep level

Comment: Does this work if the collection contains duplicate data? I'd suggest using $index https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: I think this answer was given before $index existed; using $index is probably the preferred route in later versions of KO.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it gets easier with KO 2.1: you can use $index in the foreach loop to refer to the current index.

https://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js

documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: Unfortunately it only works in foreach loops. I've tried it with knockout-sortable and the index isn't exposed there. I use Lucent's answer below.